# iOS: UIImage nil with iOS10

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm using the code below to create a UIImage.

UIImage returns nil with iOS 10.

The same code works fine with previous versions if iOS.

Any ideas on why it doesn't work for iOS 10?

```
NSString *fileURL = @"https://MyServer.info/MyService/myFile.jpg";

UIImage * i;

NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL              
                 URLWithString:fileURL]];

i = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: Do you have  image here

Comment: try  to change the url for image use this  https://fbcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-0/p480x480/15027953_1314706118596961_6215022545764764746_n.png?oh=55e8555803096611b651afe2dc822201&oe=58CFF677&__gda__=1488815954_b0fab2110c085b2e9d80b6dd752a6a36

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I changed the URL for privacy. The actual server does have an image and its viewable with a browser.  I tried your image link and it works for both iOS 8 and iOS 10.  My images are jpg, I wonder if I should convert then to png. Maybe its some issue with the jpg format I have.

Comment: Use a proper `NSURLConnect` or `NSURLSession` to load the image. Atleast you can see the errors.

Comment: have you enabled App Transport Security Settings in your plist

Comment: Converting the image from jpg to png before the image downloaded fixed the problem. That was easy enough to do, only a couple lines of C# code. I will look into using NSURLSession like a couple others have mentioned, that appears to be the preferred method. Still learning, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just wrong:

```
NSString *fileURL = @"https://MyServer.info/MyService/myFile.jpg";
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL              
                 URLWithString:fileURL]];
```

That is *not* a "file URL". It is a *remote* URL. And you should *never* call `dataWithContentsOfURL` on a remote URL. If you need to do networking, do *networking*. Download the image properly, using NSURLSession, like you're supposed to.